# Python: Merging all cells per row into one cell

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with that looks like this:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I have | my ball | in the |  |  |  |
| The sky | in june | is so | beautiful | at night |  |

Thi goes on for about 75.000 rows and its more text per cell. Now I want to somehow combine all cells in one row (e.g. I have my ball in the) so I have only one cell per row with the whole text in it. I have no idea how to do that.

I tried this:

```
import csv
data = []
with open('D:/Studium/Master/Masterarbeit/Datenset_NYT/nyt_s/outputfinal2.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    for row in csvfile:
        data.append(row.strip())
with open('out.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerows(data)
```

but it only throws me some random numbers.

I fould this:

```
open_file = open('text.csv', 'w')
for row in reader:
    street_number = row[9]
    street_name = row[3]

    open_file.write(street_number + ' ' + street_name + '\n')
```

but I have not only two cells but several and in every row there is a different amount of cells. I am totally lost here.

Can someone help? How can I go from row to row and combine all cells per row and save this into a csv file?

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it:

```
import csv

data = []

with open("D:/Studium/Master/Masterarbeit/Datenset_NYT/nyt_s/outputfinal2.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",") # 1
    for row in reader:
        data.append(" ".join(row)) # 2

with open("out.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in data:
        csvwriter.writerow([row]) # 3
```

Step by step:

1. You read the file as a CSV
2. You join all the columns for each row
3. You write one value per row in a single column

Comment: This unfortunately just adds an empty row between the rows but nothing more ...

Comment: I think the problem is, that the text in the cells is more complicated than in the example. One cell for example has two whole sentences with commas, and points. One row basically contains one newspaper article, which is somehow randomly split into multiple cells.

Comment: Update: I know why my text got split into different cells. I got the text out of xml files and the text splits up evertime there is a ";" . Is there a way to correct that?

Comment: @kathi94 You could replace the commas in the text with a similar-looking character like `‚` [U+201A] ([here is a list of comma variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma#Comma_variants)) and keep the comma `,` [U+002C] as the CSV delimiter. Or, conversely, keep the comma in your text and use a different CSV delimiter like `|` or whatever. Edit: Oh I just saw you meant `;`. Not sure, perhaps check the script or the program that generates the CSV.